# How to make a 360 degrees render showing the wireframe

Tags: rendering, wireframe

Hello I want to make a render of an object that rotates in 360º but I want to show the wireframe of it, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4):

A very basic setting can be:

[image]

Turning 360° is done with geometry nodes. Simply rotate around Z along time:

[image]

A modifier stack with a fireframe modifier and "replace original" unchecked and a material offset of 1:

[image]

A shader that let appear the wireframe with time:

[image]

[image] (Blender 4.0)

Comment: i love your solutions...but....this time, i personally would prefer to have it all in GN....wireframe is very easy to make with mesh to curve and curve to mesh, and i know that you know that. so why did you create a 2nd modifier here? ;) +1 anyway

Comment: @Chris ... Friday evening lazzyness, maybe :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of *Render > Render Animation*, make sure that you are in camera view and go into *View > Viewport Render Animation*, it will render what you currently see, whatever is your display mode. Afterwards in the *Video Sequencer* you can fade in this sequence with a real render:

[image]